# VB.NET - Convert UShort into boolean array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, boolean, type-conversion, ushort

I'm updating some old code written by another programmer, and i need to do some changes.
I have an unsigned integer stored into Short var and need to get its binary code in an array of bool.

How can i do this?

Comment: Edit your question and show the code. It will help to provide context.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Trevor's answer, you can use a `BitVector32` as well:

```
Dim myValue As UShort = 32
Dim bVector As New BitVector32(CInt(myValue))
```

`BitVector32` is slightly more efficient than `BitArray` but is limited to 32 bits.  `BitVector32` allows you to create *sections* in the bits for different purposes and treat them as flags.

Answer (score 0):

try this perhaps

```
    Dim MyShort As uShort = 32
    Dim oByteArray As New System.Collections.BitArray(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(MyShort))
```